# Can't change brightness of laptop in ubuntu 14.04 / 15.04

Tags: grub2, nvidia, brightness, bios, backlight

When i just try adjusting brightness, the indicator changes but the screen does not change brightness. I have tried adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to my `grub` file and also doing

`echo x > sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness`

and

`echo x > sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Brightness used to change fine but now is not working on a new ubuntu install. I am using a dell xps 14 with a NVIDIA 630M using the `nvidia-340-updates` driver & `nvidia prime`. Also supports ivybridge graphics but I am using the 630m. Thanks in advance

EDIT:
creating `/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` did not fix my issue.
Model is Dell XPS 14-l421x
kernal version `3.16.0-45-generic`
Updating to kernal `3.19.0-25-generic` and ubuntu 15.04 did not fix my issues
The problem was the bios setting "Load legacy option rom" being set to Enabled, setting this to disabled fixed my backlight.

Comment: What is your laptop model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed my problem. The solution for me was enabling "Load legacy option rom" in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

i can recommend you to upgrade to newer kernel, or you can try to create file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with this code in it:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: creating the file did not change anything.

Comment: you should create it with root permissions and you must reboot your PC after that.  Anyway that worked for me on my Acer laptop which was with i believe 3.12 kernel, but after i updated kernel to newer version issue gone completely.

What kernel ver. do you use?
Type `uname -r` in terminal and post output.

Comment: I tried again and still nothing, file was definitely created as root. my kernal is version `3.16.0-45-generic`

Comment: As i said before, i can only recommend you to install newer kernel. Because `20-intel.conf` and `acpi_backlight=vendor` solutions don't work for you, which is strange.

Comment: Updating to `3.19.0-25-generic` as well as ubuntu 15.04 did not fix my issue. turned out to be a BIOS settings problem.